# Работа с .bmp файлами

Tags: bmp, codeblocks, c

Дан файл ".bmp".

1. Найти высоту и ширину файла.
2. Переделать файл из цветного в черно-белый (установить fseek(Filname,10,0) и ... - дальше не знаю что делать. )

С первым пунктом проблем нет, но со вторым не могу разобраться, с чего начать. Если знаете какую-нибудь книгу по этой теме, подскажите, пожалуйста.  Буду благодарен, если ответите на вопрос.

Comment: Вам напрямую работать хочется или можно использовать сторонние библиотеки? Хотя, вижу fseek - Вы хотите работать напрямую. Тогда предупрежу - bmp бывают разные, много форматов. Но для начала почитали бы хотя бы википедию.

Comment: codeblocks-то тут при чем?

Answer (score 1):

http://graphics.cs.msu.ru/sites/default/files/gltutorialcourse2.pdf

Страница 178